# Search multiple words in web page with a regular expression or other means

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I want to search in a Chrome page multiple words

For example `*basket*nike*120*` for the line "i buy basket from Nike for 120 dollars"

If the words matches it shows me the line.

I know it’s possible with regex, if someone could tell me the right expression.

Comment: “I know it’s possible with regex, if someone could tell me the right expression.” Does in page searching in Chrome support regular expressions? I thought it was just via simple text patterns. I wonder if there is an extension that supports regular expression in page searches.

Answer (score 1):

Native Chrome does not support highlighting multiple words, with or
without regex.

You need an extension for that :
[Multiple Search and Highlight](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/doagleaopbffngpffnmnajoiablpakfj)

> Highlight multiple words separated by comma, space or arbitrary separator with persistent history

The comments on this extension note that it cannot highlight words
that are inside nested `<iframe>` HTTP tags.

Another extension is
[Multi Search & Multi Jump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-search-multi-jump/oahidkobkdbfbknbloljgpjbeaefgapa/)
and still another is
[efTwo](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/eftwo-f2-advanced-find-on/ccaikggmppdolhcehimngikgiafmdcep).

---

For regex searches, you could use the extension
[Chrome Regex Search](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn) :

> An extension for Regex Search in lieu of Chrome's CTRL+F
>
> Highlight regex matches on the web page dynamically as you type.

Answer (score 0):

As harrymc suggested, you can use the [Chrome Regex Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn) extension to run a regular expression search.

To open the search field, hit `Ctrl+Shift+F`.

The regular expression you need is something like `basket.*nike.*120`.

The dot `.` matches any character and the asterisk `*` quantifier following it indicates that you are OK with any number of them (they may be different characters). To make the search case-insensitive, toggle the *i* button that sits three buttons to the right of the search field.

This way, all the matches will be highlighted disregarding capitalization.

Comment: Thank you i’m Going to test it